How can I retrieve product metadata from a session after completing checkout with Stripe in a Spring Boot application?
Using the Stripe SDK in Spring Boot, after creating a session and adding your product data, you have the option to use putAllMetadata, which accepts a map of <String, String>. The purpose of adding this metadata is to retrieve it after a successful payment, via the webhook.
I have implemented the webhook and received a Session object from it, but I am unable to find a method to retrieve this metadata.
 paramsBuilder.addLineItem(
       SessionCreateParams.LineItem.builder()
              .setQuantity(1L)
              .setPriceData(
                  PriceData.builder()
                       .setProductData(
                           PriceData.ProductData
                                .builder()
                                .putAllMetadata(metadata)
                                .setName("Book "))
                                .build())
                       .setCurrency(myDTO.getCurrency())
                       .setUnitAmountDecimal(BigDecimal.valueOf(myDTO.getPrice()* 100))
                       .build())
              .build());
                Session session = Session.create(paramsBuilder.build());
                return session.getUrl();


I have tried retrieving it from the session

 switch (event.getType()) {
        case "payment_intent.succeeded": {
            // System.out.println("done");
            // System.out.println("succeeded " + stripeObject.toJson());
            break;
         }
         case "charge.updated": {
             // System.out.println("upda " + stripeObject.toJson());
         }
         case "checkout.session.completed":
             Session sessionEvent = (Session) stripeObject;
             handleCheckoutSessionCompleted(sessionEvent);
             // System.out.print("sessiom " + sessionEvent.toJson());
             break;
             // ... handle other event types
         default:
             System.out.println("Unhandled event type: " + event.getType());
   }
return ResponseEntity.ok("");
}

private void handleCheckoutSessionCompleted(Session session) {
       try {
             SessionListLineItemsParams params = SessionListLineItemsParams.builder().build();
             List<LineItem> lineItems = session.listLineItems(params).getData();

             for (LineItem item : lineItems) {
                String this = item.getPrice().getMetadata()
                                                .get("this");
                System.out.println("this is "+ this);
             }
       } catch (StripeException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
       } catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
       }
}


// System.out.print("sessiom " + sessionEvent.toJson()); This line of code correctly prints the session  object.
My code prints this is null to the console.

The problem seems to be that to access the metadata you can only get it using the expand parameter. In this case, the metadata is under the data.price.product and can never be accessed from the session except explicitly requested. Stripe doesn't give you the full object.
A big thanks to soma too for pointing out the correct method I was supposed to use. There is indeed metadata in both the price and product objects.
SessionListLineItemsParams params = SessionListLineItemsParams.builder()
             .addExpand("data.price.product") //can't get product data without this
             .build();
List<LineItem> lineItems = session.listLineItems(params).getData();

String this = item.getPrice().getProductObject().getMetadata().get("this");

https://docs.stripe.com/api/expanding_objects
https://docs.stripe.com/expand

You can’t receive webhook events with properties auto-expanded.
Objects sent in events are always in their minimal form. To access
nested values in expandable properties, you must retrieve the object
in a separate call within your webhook handler.


If I understand correctly, you have a Checkout Session object, and want to retrieve the metadata set on the associated Products? If so you need to:

Get the Checkout Session object
Get the Line Items of the Checkout Session
Get all the Price in the Line Items
For each Price, find the corresponding Product (that's the step you are missing)
Find the metadata of the Product

An alternative would be to set the metadata directly on the Checkout Session object itself or on the Price object.

Still returning null- item.getPrice().getProductObject().getMetadata().get("this");

@J.E.N Are you sure you correctly set the this metadata on the Product object? You can open the object in the dashboard to see if it has metadata or not.

Yes, it's showing in the logs on the dashboard. The problem was that Stripe doesn't send the whole children object unless you request it in the SessionListLineItemsParams builder. Thanks a lot.
